# Should I use Facebook FQL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Koala gem to interact with Facebook Graph API. [In its Github](https://github.com/arsduo/koala), the authors mentioned that Koala also supports Facebook REST API, which will be deprecated in the future, and give this example:

```
@rest = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)    
@rest.fql_query(my_fql_query) # convenience method
@rest.fql_multiquery(fql_query_hash) # convenience method
@rest.rest_call("stream.publish", arguments_hash) # generic version
```

My take from this is that `FQL` is a part of the REST api, and that I shouldn't use it if I don't have to. I couldn't confirm this by googling.

Is it true that FQL is part of REST api? If so, should I avoid it when possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), FQL is nearly completely deprecated and **you shouldn't use it for new projects** (and also should migrate existing projects away from it as soon as possible). My old answer is below for posterity.

---

You can also make FQL query requests against the Graph API, like so:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fql?
    q=SELECT%20uid,%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20=%2015504121
```

Yields:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "uid": 15504121,
            "name": "Jimmy Sawczuk"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Jimmy, does this mean that FQL won't be deprecated in the future? My understanding after reading your answer is: FQL is re-implemented with Graph API and will stay with it.

Comment: Correct. There's no evidence [in documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) that it's going to be deprecated, and it's pretty widely used (on both the REST endpoint and the Graph endpoint).

Comment: [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) says now: "On August 17, 2016, FQL will no longer be available and cannot be queried."

Answer (score 6):

You better do not user fql.

See this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

> Version 2.0 of the Facebook Platform API is the last version where FQL
>   will be available. Versions after 2.0 will not support FQL. Please
>   migrate your applications to use Graph API instead of FQL. Please see
>   our changelog for current version information.

Comment: Why did they deprecate FQL?! Technical or marketing reasons. Can't find answer in google.

Answer (score 5):

FQL has been deprecated from version 2.1.